# Erro em Insert com FK

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho duas tabelas, Cliente e Plano, que possuem o relacionamento `1:1`. Tenho 3 planos cadastrados no banco com seus respectivos dados. Mas ao tentar inserir um Cliente que possui uma `Foreing Key` que é referente ao `Id` do Plano escolhido. No momento de inserir os dados tenho o seguinte erro:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Cliente.Planos_ClienteId\". 
>   The conflict occurred in database \"MeuBanco\", table \"dbo.Planos\", column 'PlanoId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Minha `query`

```
insert into Clientes values(NEWID(),'Nome do Cliente', '000.000.000-52', '001122','14966034-BC78-4B77-B817-4EC7AC483B05','logradouro','bairro','cep', 'telefone','email');
```

Este é o valor do `Id` do Plano existente no banco de dados:

`14966034-BC78-4B77-B817-4EC7AC483B05`

`Select` do banco:

[image: Resultado do Select]

Comment: Uma dúvida, porque você utiliza o `NEWID()` para preencher a PK?

Comment: o `Newid()` gera a `Id` de maneira automática no momento da execução assim não preciso gerar manualmente, a `PK` é do tipo `Guid`....

Comment: JcSaint, tem gato aí... Ou esse `Id` não existia na tabela `Planos` no momento da inserção ou os parâmetros do `insert` estão na ordem errada (tente especificar os campos) ou tem algum problema na *constraint*. Você consegue incluir um exemplo mais completo com o DDL das tabelas + dados? Talvez algo do [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Execute um `sp_help` na tabela planos e veja se realmente a `constraint` está sendo preenchida.

Comment: O @AnthonyAccioly tem razão. Precisamos de mais informações para conseguir te ajudar. Aparentemente parece mesmo um erro "_bobo_" de posição dos valores referente as colunas.

Comment: É recomendável você especificar os campos no `insert`: `insert into Clientes ([campos]) values ([valores])` assim não tem como errar, e se, inclusive, acrescentar novos campos na tabela, seu `insert` não para de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Quando for criar a tabela

CREATE TABLE Clientes
  (
     idCliente INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)   CONSTRAINT PK_Clientes PRIMARY KEY (idCliente),
     NomeCliente             VARCHAR(255)
  )

com o IDENTITY (1, 1) não será necessario o NEWid() nos inserts